# when i armature clothes to character sleeves are flying

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

[image: what can be my mistake? slevers are not in the same position as arms]what can be my mistake?
**slevers are not in the same position as arms .**

Comment: Are the sleeves and arms in the same position before you added the armature? Do they have the same rest position?

Comment: yes before I added an armature I matched them same position, but when I enabled an armature sleeves goes down , and arms stayed in the same position

Comment: It looks like the pullover and the body are separate objects. When you move the control bone of the arm then the arm and the sleeve both move? If the body works you can transfer the weights with a *Data Transfer* modifier to the pullover. But the meshes must be in the same rest position.

Comment: If you want you can share the file so we have a look